# Inequality for a polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

Let $p_n$ be a polynomial of exact degree $n$. I would like to show that $f(z) = e
^{p_n(z)}$ has genus and order equal to $n$.

By definition the order is $\lambda=lim_{r\to +\infty} sup \frac{log\Big(log(M(r)\Big)}{log r}$ where $M(r)=max_{|z|=r}|f(z)|$

For that i need to prove that there exist positive constants  $c_1,c'_1,c_2, c'_2$  such that
$$c_2e^{c'_2R^n}\le |M(R)|\le c_1e^{c'_1R^n}$$ 
for any $R$ large enough.

Comment: What about taking $c_2'$ just as the opposite of $c_1'$? :D

Comment: the constants should be all positive

Comment: Then there is something odd. If $p_n(z)=-z^2$, there is no positive constant that works in the LHS.

Comment: In fact my initial problem is:Let $p_n$ be a polynomial of exact degree $n$. Show that $f(z) = e
^{p_n(z)}$ has genus and order equal to $n$.
where the order is given by:$\lambda=lim_{r\to +\infty} sup \frac{log\Big(log(M(r)\Big)}{log r}$ with $M(r)=max_{|z|=r}|f(z)|$

Comment: To prove that $\max_{|z|=r}|f(z)|$ fulfills some inequality is not the same as proving that $|f(z)|$ alone fulfills some inequality, in particular if we are dealing with lower bounds!

Comment: how to do then . Help me please

Comment: To write down a correct statement should be a good starting point. Voting for closing.

Comment: I edit the statement, I have an exam tomorow and i didn't mannage to prove that. I will be thankful if you help me .

Comment: just write $p_n(z)$ as $C\prod_{k=1}^{n}(z-\zeta_k)$ and perform some trivial estimations by assuming that $r$ is larger than twice the maximum modulus of $\zeta_k$. Are you aware of the inequality linking the number of zeroes of a holomorphic function in a disk with its behaviour on the boundary?

Comment: $p_n(z)=C\prod_{k=1}^{n}(z-\zeta_k)$ then $|e^{p_n(z)}|=|e^{C\prod_{k=1}^{n}(z-\zeta_k)}|$ and we take $r\ge 2 max_{1\le k\le n}|\zeta_k|$ then i didn't understand what to write and i don't know  the inequality linking the number of zeroes of a holomorphic function in a disk with its behaviour on the boundary.